# Can I connect three TP-Links of two types?

Tags: powerline-networking

I'm using two TP Links at the moment at home. It's working fine using two of the smaller boxes (on the right in the image) but now I want to connect a third one.

I only have two of the smaller ones and got a third one from someone who wasn't using it.
I assumed these were plug and play devices. Plug them in and they work fine. But I can't get the bigger one to connect to the other two.

Is there anything I can do to get them to connect?

Images:

[image]

[image]

Ok, model numbers, the pair that work: TL-PA411

The big single one: TL-PA11(UK) Ver: 1.1

They both have MAC addresses and passwords.

When different pairs are used the network just says "Unidentified Network"

Here's a shot of ipconfig. First time it was with the working TP Link, the second time with the not working one. I've removed addresses, not sure if it's necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should provide more details to help with the problem, including a network diagram to show the connection configuration, and also results of traceroutes from behind various routers.   Also, model numbers for the equipment is important so we can see what kind of devices they are and a better problem description (ie are you just having problems reaching the router or are you having issues reaching the outside world)

Routers are not "Plug and Play", although they do often "just work" on the default settings.  Its quite likely that you have 2 routers trying to work with the same addresses and this is causing you issues.     If this is the case you need to change the IP range for the LAN of 1 or more of the routers so it does not conflict.

Powerline Devices

Your updated answer made me question of these devices are routers (most common TPLink gear is) - I now suspect they are Powerline networking devices.  If so, they should be able to work together however there may be obstacles in the path stopping the signals working - most common are

- Distance Issues
- Line filters
- RCD's  (commonly circuits with different protection circuitry at the switchboard)
- -> NOTE <- You may need to pair the devices so they can talk to each other.
- A distantly unlikely third possibility may be some incompatibility negotiating 
  encryption or the like.

To test if the devices work - Try plugging the larger device (which I speculate is the router) and the smaller devices (which I suspect are bridge endpoints on the LAN side) to the same power strip - ideally one without a filter - and see if they work.  Then try different plug points to see what happens and build a "reliability map" - some points may work better then others.

Also, you should look at the status of the lights which may tell you if things are working.  You might

Unlike a router they do not require an IP address (they behave like a switch).    The Error you are seeing would imply that the Powerlink devices can't talk to each other and thus can't create a "virtual switch".  As a result the client can't get an IP address and things don't work.

Looking at [this link](http://uk.tp-link.com/article/?faqid=258) it appears you will need to set the devices up to pair with each other - particularly if your current devices are already paired.  (You can apparently pair the device with any existing adaptors, and once its paired it will see all the other adaptors).   Pairing is done by holding the pair link for 1 second on a working adaptor and about then (depending on the model) 1 or 5 seconds on the adaptor to pair within 2 minutes - Alternatively their is software you can download to pair using a computer.

Comment: Great thanks, so it's possible, that's good, I'll post some more image

Comment: Please see amended answer which talks about Powerline devices - which you probably have.

Comment: Nice, I've finally got it. I was trying the pairing button, but it only just worked when I plugged both into the socket, unplugged the ethernet cable, pressed pair, then plugged the ethernet back in
Thanks so much for the help and advice!

Comment: Ok, and to get all three to work: Plug all three in, unplug all ethernet cables, press the pair on the router side, pair on the two PC sides, then plug all three cables in

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the one from @mikey mouse, Jan 23, 20:30, 2015. Even today in 2023, I can pair two TP-Link TL-PA411 and one TL-WPA4220

- plug all devices
- unplug all ethernet cables
- press pair on the device to be connected to the router
- press pair on the remaining two devices
- plug all three cables in